# Exercise on expression with matrices using Cayley-Hamilton theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, characteristic-polynomial, cayley-hamilton

For the following matrix $$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I need to use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem to calculate $(A+I_3)^{10}(A-I_3)^2+A$

First I try writing the characteristic polynomial $f(t)=\det(A-tI_3)=-t^3+t^2+2t-1$. Then, by using Caylely-Hamilton, I have that $f(A)=O_3$, that is, $$-A^3+A^2+2A-I_3=O_3$$
$$A^3-A^2-2A+I_3=O_3$$
I decompose the previous expression and I get that $$(A+I_3)(A-I_3)^2=A$$
Now I replace the last expression in the initial expression $(A+I_3)^{10}(A-I_3)^2+A$ and get $$(A+I_3)^9(A+I_3)(A-I_3)^2+A=$$
$$=(A+I_3)^9A+A$$

Now what should the next step be?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how fruitful your approach will be.  One method that will work is as follows: with polynomial long-division, we find that
$$
(t + 1)^{10}(t - 1)^2 + t = q(t)(t^3 - t^2 - 2t + 1) + 4631 t^2 + 3721 t  - 2560.
$$
Thus, we have
$$
(A + I)^{10}(A - I)^2 + A = 4631 A^2 + 3721A  - 2560 I.
$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
   \det(\lambda I-A)&=\left|
                         \begin{array}{ccc}
                            \lambda & -1 & 0 \\
                            -1 & \lambda & -1 \\
                             0 & -1 & \lambda-1
                           \end{array}
                      \right| \\
      & = \lambda(\lambda(\lambda-1)-1)+((-1)(\lambda-1)) \\
      & = \lambda^2(\lambda-1)-(\lambda-1) \\
      & =(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda+1).
\end{align}
Therefore $(A-I)^2(A+I)=0$. You are asked to compute $(A+I)^{10}(A-I)^2+A$, which must be the same as $A$ because $(A+I)^{10}(A-I)^2$ has $(A-I)^2(A+I)$ as a factor.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* The result is a matrix with integer coeffcients, namely
$$
\begin{pmatrix}    2070 & 3722 & 4631 \cr
      3722 & 6701 & 8353 \cr
      4631 & 8353 & 10423 \end{pmatrix}
$$
So you need to evaluate at a certain point.

Comment: What is that should be evaluated?

Comment: $(A+I_3)^{10}(A-I_3)^2+A$ should be evaluated. This can be done by replacing $A^3$ repeatedly, ending up with $rA^2+sA+tI$, which you have to compute (evaluate).

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the last expression as
$$(A+I)^9A+A = (((A+I)^3)^2+I)A = \begin{bmatrix}    2070 & 3722 & 4631 \cr
      3722 & 6701 & 8353 \cr
      4631 & 8353 & 10423 \end{bmatrix}$$
with only $4$ matrix multiplications and $2$ additions with identity $I$ which shouldn't be hard.